# Including JSP page inside forEach loop

Tags: java, jsp

I need to do for each loop and include loops content to other jsp page. Now I need to pass looped variable to other JSP page. I have tried following, but it didn't work. When I used attribute in included page, it just returned null value.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="loop">    
    <jsp:include page="/my_jsp_page.jsp" flush="true">
        <jsp:param name="item" value="${item}" />
    </jsp:include>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The code posted as far looks fine. You need to post more detail about the other file and also about "an exception" which you received.

Comment: why not pass all items instead of each item and use for loop in "my_jsp_page.jsp"? what's so specific on passing each item over all items?

Answer (score 3):

You can store the "item" into request attribute before call jsp:include

```
<c:set var="item" scope="request" value="${item}">
```

then read it from the request scope

Answer (score 1):

This is because `jsp:param` sets a request *parameter*, not a request *attribute*.

From within your included page, you'll have to refer to `item` like this:

```
${param['item']}
```

Note that, since we're talking about request *parameters* here, those parameters will *always* be strings. If this doesn't do it for you, you should follow @Boris' advice above.